# ASP.NET MVC @Html.RenderAction of a different content type

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

just before the end of my `<body>` I'm trying to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("RenderData4JS", "Helper"); }
</script>
```

Which return Json(Data4JS) . Basically it just outputs Json so I can access it with jQuery.

When I do this so, the whole webpage, then shows the HTML source (Must be changing the content-type of the whole website).

How can I get around this, or is there another way? (I don't want to AJAX)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out how out do it, (elegantly enough)

//In your ActionResult Action

```
return Content(GlobalHelper.ObjectToJson("GeneralData", Data4JS.Get()));
```

//In some Utility class:

```
public static string ObjectToJson(string objectName, object o)
        {
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            return "{\"Data4JS\":" + jsonSerializer.Serialize(o) + "}";
        }
```

Comment: I like this option because you can append dynamic properties to an object at any point in the request lifecycle (by storing in the Session), then just before your body closes you Json it so your JS gets a beautiful little object to work with, without having to mess around with a dirty ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You could get the result of that action into some object ("probably a string") and return it with the object you are using as the Model for that view.  In your script section you could pass in that variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x =  @Model.test
...Do whatever you need with the test string
</script>
```

I don't recommend this however and I think you would be better off making an ajax call with JQuery